# How can I lookup data from one column, when the value I'm referencing changes columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to do an `INDEX-MATCH`-like lookup between two documents, except my `MATCH's index array` doesn't stay in one column.
In Vague-English: I want a value from a known column that matches another value that may be found in any column.

Refer to the image below. Let's call everything to the left of the bold vertical line on column H doc1, and the right side will be doc2.

Doc2 has a column "Find This", which will be the `INDEX's array`.  It is compared with "ID1" from doc1 (Note that the values in "Find This" will *not* be in the same order as column ID1, but it's easier to undertsand this way).

The "[Result]" column in doc2 will be the value from doc1's "Want This" column from the row that matches "FIND THIS" ...However, sometimes the value from "FIND THIS" is not in the "ID1" column, and is instead in "ID2","ID3", etc.
So, I'm trying to generate Col K from Col J. This would be like pressing `Ctrl+F` and searching for a value in Col J, then taking the value from Col D in that row and copying it to Col K.

I made identical values from a column the same color in the other doc to make it easier to visualize where they are coming from.

[image: Example documents]

Note also that in column F of doc1, the same value from doc2's "Find This" can be found after some other text. 
Also note that the column headers are only there as examples, the ID columns are not actually numbered.

I would simply hard-code the correct column to search from, but I'm not in control of doc1, and I'm worried that future versions may have new "ID" columns, with other's being removed.

I'd prefer this to be a solution in the form of a formula, but VB will do.

Comment: how do you know that what you are looking for is AZSD1 in column E and not WHATEVER in F or whatever 2 in G etc.  Right now if I understand the pattern is the value in J is in the row that corresponds to K.

Comment: You want to search for the 'Find This' value from doc 2 in doc 1 and when that value is found in any column you want the 'Want This' column value from that same row to be put into your Result column?  Do I have that correct?

Comment: How do you know for you last entry to go back to ID1 to the left and not take if from somewhere on the right?

Comment: @zack.lore You are correct. I've edited my question to be more explicit.

Comment: @Bort Scott brought up a good point.  I had assumed all IDs column J that you are searching for would be UNIQUE.  Is your list in J only unique items in terms that they will only be found by themselves once in columns B:H.  I understand that Column F they will be compounded with other words which makes column F different.  IF a value from column J can be found both in column B and Column H, do you want the first, last, or some other numbered occurrence to be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate column K based on given values of column J then you could use the following:

```
=INDEX(doc1!$D$2:$D$14,SUMPRODUCT((doc1!$B$2:$H$14=J2)*ROW(doc1!$B$2:$H$14))-1)
```

Copy that formula down as far as you need to go.

It basically only returns the row of the where a matching column J is found.  we then find that row in the index of your D range to get your value in K.

Proof of concept:

[image: Proof of concept]

### UPDATE:

If you are working with non unique entities n column J.  That is the value on its own can be found in multiple rows and columns.  Consider using the following to return the Last row where there J value is found:

```
=INDEX(doc1!$D$2:$D$14,AGGREGATE(14,6,(doc1!$B$2:$H$14=J2)*ROW(doc1!$B$2:$H$14),1)-1)
```

### UPDATE 2:

And to return the first row where what you are looking in column J is found use:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$14,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($B$2:$H$14=J2)*ROW($B$2:$H$14)-1,1))
```

Thanks to Scott Craner for the hint on the minimum formula.

To determine if you have UNIQUE data from column J in your range B2:H14 you can enter this array formula.  In order to enter an array formula you need to press CTRL+SHFT+ENTER at the same time and not just ENTER.  You will know you have done it right when you see {} around your formula in the formula bar.  You cannot at the {} manually.

```
=IF(MAX(COUNTIF($B$2:$H$14,J2:J14))>1,"DUPLICATES","UNIQUE")
```

### UPDATE 3

[AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) - A relatively new function to me but goes back to Excel 2010.  Aggregate is 19 functions rolled into 1.  It would be nice if they all worked the same way but they do not.   I think it is functions numbered 14 and up that will perform the same way an array formula or a CSE formula if you prefer.  The nice thing is you do not need to use CSE when entering or editing them.  SUMPRODUCT is another example of a regular formula that performs array formula calculations.

The meat of this explanation I believe is what is happening inside of the AGGREGATE brackets.  If you click on the link you will get an idea of what the first two arguments are.  The first defines which function you are using, and the second tell AGGREGATE how to deal with Errors, hidden rows, and some other nested functions.  That is the relatively easy part.  What I believe you want to know is what is happening with this:

```
(doc1!$B$2:$H$14=J2)*ROW(doc1!$B$2:$H$14)
```

For illustrative purpose lets reduce this formula to something a little smaller in scale that does the same thing.  I'll avoid starting in A1 as that can make life a little easier when counting since it the 1st row and first column.  So by placing the example range outside of it you can see some more special considerations potentially.

What I want to know is what row each of the items list in Column C occurs in column B

```
  |    B     |    C
3 | DOG      |  PLATYPUS
4 | CAT      |  DOG
5 | PLATYPUS |
```

The full formula for our mini example would be:

```
{=($B$3:$B$5=C2)*ROW($B$3:$B$5)}
```

And we are going to look at the following as an array

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$5,AGGREGATE(14,6,($B$3:$B$5=C2)*ROW($B$3:$B$5),1)-2)
```

So the first brackets is going to be a Boolean array as you noted.  Every cell that is TRUE will TRUE until its forced into a math calculation.  When that happens, True becomes 1 and False becomes 0.I that formula was entered as a CSE formula and place in D2, it would break down as follows:

```
FALSE  X  3
FALSE  X  4
TRUE   X  5
```

The 3, 4 and 5 come from ROW() returning the value of the row number that it is dealing with at the time of the array math operation.  Little trick, we could have had ROW(1:3).  Just need to make sure the size of the array matches!  This is not matrix math is just straight across multiplication.  And since the Boolean is now experiencing a math operation we are now looking at:

```
0 X 3 = 0
0 X 4 = 0
1 X 5 = 5
```

So the array of {0,0,5} gets handed back to the aggregate for more processing.  The important thing to note here is that it contains ONLY 0 and the individual row numbers where we had a match.  So with the first aggregate formula, formula 14 was chosen which is the [LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LARGE-function-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64) function. And we also told it to ignore errors, which in this particular case does not matter.  So after providing the array to the aggregate function, there was a `,1)` to finish off the aggregate  function.  The 1 tells the aggregate function that we want the 1st larges number when the array is sorted from smallest to largest.  If that number was 2 it would be the 2nd largest number and so on.  So the last row or the only row that something is found on is returned.  So in our small example it would be 5.

But wait that 5 was buried inside another function called Index.  and in our small example that INDEX formula would be:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$5,AGGREGATE(...)-2)
```

Well we know that the range is only 3 rows long, so asking for the 5th row, would have excel smacking you up side the head with an error because your index number is out of range.  So in comes the header row correction of -1 in the original formula or -2 for the small example and what we really see for the small example is:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$5,5-2)
=INDEX($B$3:$B$5,3)
```

and here is a weird bit of info, That last one does not become PLATYPUS...it becomes the cell reference to =B5 which pulls PLATYPUS.  But that little nuance is a story for another time.

Now in the comments Scott essentially told me to invert for the error to get the first row.  And this is important step for the aggregate and it had me running in circles for awhile.  So the full equation for the first row option in our mini example is

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($B$3:$B$5=C2)*ROW($B$3:$B$5),1)-2)
```

And what Scott Craner was actually suggesting which Skips one math step is:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$3:$B$5)/($B$3:$B$5=C2),1)-2)
```

However since I only realized this after writing this all up the explanation will continue with the first of these two equations

So the important thing to note here is the change from function 14 to function 15 which is [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07).  Think of it a finding the minimum.  And this time that 6 plays a huge factor along with the 1/.  So our array in the middle this time equates to:

```
1/FALSE X 3
1/FALSE X 4
1/TRUE  X 5
```

Which then becomes:

```
1/0 X 3
1/0 X 4
1/1 X 5
```

Which then has excel slapping you up side the head again because you are trying to divide by 0:

```
#div/0 X 3
#div/0 X 4
   1/1 X 5
```

But you were smart and you protected yourself from that slap upside the head when you told AGGREGATE to ignore error when you used 6 as the second argument/reference!  Therefore what is above becomes:

```
{5}
```

Since we are performing a [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07), and we passed ,1) as the closing part of the AGGREGATE, we have essentially said give me the minimum row number or the 1st smallest number of the resulting array when sorted in ascending order.

The rest plays out the same as it did for the LARGE AGGREGATE method.  The pitfall I fell into originally is I did not use the 1/ to force an error.  As a result, every time I tried getting the SMALL of the array I was getting 0 from all the false results.

SUMPRODUCT works in a very similar fashion, but only works when your result array in the middle only returns 1 non zero answer.  The reason being is the last step of the SUMPRODUCT function is to all the individual elements of the resulting array.  So if you only have 1 non zero, you get that non zero number.  If you had two rows that matched for instance 12 and 31, then the SUMPRODUCT method would return 43 which is not any of the row numbers you wanted, where as aggregate large would have told you 31 and aggregate small would have told you 12.

Comment: Did you test that? The column headers don't have the ID numbers.

Comment: @teylyn Where did it say the column headers dont have ID numbers?  I must have missed that part.

Comment: Column J is already established. The OP wants the formula for the result in column K in the screenshot of the question.

Comment: @teylyn his screen shot has ID2 and ID3 and ID4  they are just not in the header row.  Its how I was basing what number to bring over.  HOWEVER in hindsight, I think I miss understood the question and he is trying to generate column K based on given values in column J.

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying to generate K from J, sorry for my confusing question. I also should have mentioned that the headers "ID[#]" are just example headers.

Comment: @Tetlyn and I had interpreted the Q as find this based on my results. I was wrong. However its been cleared up now.  Its also why I prefaced original answer with "If I understood.."

Comment: @Bort  All good,  its what happens when there are uncertainties and answers are given prior to clarification.  With things cleared up you have multiple approaches options to choose from for what suits you best.

Comment: @ForwardEd  - You are saying that teylyn's current answer is solving the wrong problem? I'm going to try testing these now, I'll update with results..

Comment: @Bort no, not at all, TEYLYN's answer is good!  it does what you want it to do, she provided that in proof of a screen shot. heck I even upvoted her answer!  I was the one that was originally backwards.  I deleted that part of my question when I got the clarification.  Both Tetlyn's and my updated answer should work.  I am assuming the VBA solution works as well.

Comment: So, what happens when there is more than one value that matches.  With your sumproduct it will add the two rows together and create an error.  IMO use the aggregate or min(if()) to get the first one only.

Comment: @ScottCranerI had tested that with the partial martch.  ie. column F has blah + ID being searched for.  It was working with that.  IF IDs are not unique then yes problems ensue!

Comment: @ScottCraner I figured out how to return the last row, but the first row is eluding me.  I tried the 1st small row number, but that is 0.  I tried throwing an if statement into the aggregate to make 0 results "" and that just made the thing return an error.  I know there is a way to return the 1st row but its currently eluding me 8(  I think the 30C+ temperatures fried my brain today.  I dont do well when its above 20C

Comment: @ForwardEd - Both your formulas worked in my example file. Hopefully they will work with the real documents tomorrow! Noob question: For your first formula (for non-uniques), dragging the fill handle doesn't work, as the index array shifts down with the next row, so the results are exponentially shifted. If I recall, there is a way to use absolutes instead of relatives, right?

Your 2nd formula seems to fill just fine. Thanks! Now to test the other answers..

Comment: @Bort I just tried copying and pasting both formulas into an excel sheet.  After deleting the 'doc1'! references, as they try and make excel open a work sheet that I do not have, I did a drag down and the only letter that changed was the J2.  When adjust the other ranges to suit your data, ensure you have a $ in front the letter and the number.  ensure the reference to J2 has no $ in front of the 2 as the 2 needs to change as you copy/drag down.

Comment: Divide the row by the boolean do not multiply.

Comment: @ScottCraner You left out the first step!  Apply palm of hand swiftly to forehead, then proceed with option 6 ignore errors!

Comment: @ForwardEd - What in the world is going on with "AGGREGATE(...)"? I tried breaking it down with "Evaluate Formula" but I'm still lost. I can make out that the multiplicand (doc1!$B$2:$H$14=J2) becomes a boolean array of comparisons with the J value. Then that is multiplied by ROW(...). But ROW(....) by itself returns an integer. So in the formula, it magically becomes an array. After AGGREGATE(...), it will then evaluate to the correct row #, but then 1 is subtracted. What even?

Comment: Subtract 1 because you have a header row,  if your header row was 5 lines it would be minus 5.  What is going on inside the aggregate function is an array formula without having to do the CSE part. The gist with the multiplication is that only the row where something is true in the logical part is returned as false is 0 and true is 1

Comment: @Bort See Update 3 and if that explains it sufficiently.  You may want to wear a helmet d:)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe, starting in K2 and copied down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(J2,B:B,0),-1),IFERROR(MATCH(J2,E:E,0),-1),IFERROR(MATCH(J2,G:G,0),-1),IFERROR(MATCH(J2,H:H,0),-1))),"")
```

[image]

If you want to keep the positions of the columns for the Match variable, consider creating generic range names for each column you want to check, like "Col1", "Col2", "Col3". Create a few more range names than you think you will need and reference them to `=$B:$B`, `=$E:$E` etc. Plug all range names into Match functions inside the Max() statement as above.

When columns are added or removed from the table, adjust the range name definitions to the columns you want to check.

For example, if you set up the formula with five Matches inside the Max(), and the table changes so you only want to check three columns, point three of the range names to the same column. The Max() will only return one result and one lookup, even if the same column is matched several times.

Comment: I verified that this works, though I have to manually add or remove terms every time a column in doc1 is added or removed. For my specific case, I prefer Future Ed's solution because it searches a range of columns and doesn't need a term for each column. However, I'm sure there may be scenarios where only specific columns should be searched, and this solution will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a vba solution if I understood correctly:

```
Sub DisplayActiveRange()
    Dim sheetToSearch As Worksheet
        Set sheetToSearch = Sheet2
    Dim sheetToOutput As Worksheet
        Set sheetToOutput = Sheet1

    Dim search As Range
    Dim output As Range
    Dim searchCol As String
        searchCol = "J"
    Dim outputCol As String
        outputCol = "K"
    Dim valueCol As String
        valueCol = "D"
    Dim r As Range

    Dim currentRow As Integer
        currentRow = 1
    Dim maxRow As Integer
        maxRow = sheetToOutput.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For currentRow = 1 To maxRow

        Set search = Range("J" & currentRow)

        For Each r In sheetToSearch.UsedRange

            If r.Value <> "" Then
                If r.Value = search.Value Then

                    Set output = sheetToOutput.Range(outputCol & currentRow)
                    output.Value = sheetToSearch.Range(valueCol & currentRow).Value

                    currentRow = currentRow + 1
                    Set search = sheetToOutput.Range(searchCol & currentRow)

                End If
            End If

        Next

    Next currentRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways of doing it, but this will give you what you want. We assume headers in both "source" and "destination" sheets. You will need to adapt the "Const" declarations according to how your sheets are named. Press Control & G in Excel to bring up the VBA window and copy and paste this code into "This Workbook" under the "VBA Project" group, then select "Run" from the menu:

```
        Option Explicit

    Private Const sourceSheet = "Source"
    Private Const destSheet = "Destination"

    Public Sub FindColumns()

        Dim rowCount As Long
        Dim foundValue As String

        Sheets(destSheet).Select

        rowCount = 1 'Assume a header row

        Do While Range("J" & rowCount + 1).value <> ""

            rowCount = rowCount + 1
            foundValue = FncFindText(Range("J" & rowCount).value)
            Sheets(destSheet).Select
            Range("K" & rowCount).value = foundValue

        Loop

    End Sub

    Private Function FncFindText(value As String) As String

        Dim rowLoop As Long
        Dim colLoop As Integer
        Dim found As Boolean
        Dim pos As Long

        Sheets(sourceSheet).Select
        rowLoop = 1
        colLoop = 0

        Do While Range(alphaCon(colLoop + 1) & rowLoop + 1).value <> "" And found = False

            rowLoop = rowLoop + 1

            Do While Range(alphaCon(colLoop + 1) & rowLoop).value <> "" And found = False

                colLoop = colLoop + 1

                pos = InStr(Range(alphaCon(colLoop) & rowLoop).value, value)

                If pos > 0 Then

                    FncFindText = Mid(Range(alphaCon(colLoop) & rowLoop).value, pos, Len(value))
                    found = True

                End If

            Loop

            colLoop = 0

        Loop

    End Function

    Private Function alphaCon(aNumber As Integer) As String

    Dim letterArray As String
    Dim iterations As Integer

    letterArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

        If aNumber <= 26 Then

            alphaCon = (Mid$(letterArray, aNumber, 1))

        Else

            If aNumber Mod 26 = 0 Then

                iterations = Int(aNumber / 26)
                alphaCon = (Mid$(letterArray, iterations - 1, 1)) & (Mid$(letterArray, 26, 1))

            Else

                'we deliberately round down using 'Int' as anything with decimal places is not a full iteration.
                iterations = Int(aNumber / 26)
                alphaCon = (Mid$(letterArray, iterations, 1)) & (Mid$(letterArray, (aNumber - (26 * iterations)), 1))

            End If

        End If

    End Function
```

Comment: Ctrl & G? In windows, that is showing me the "Goto" window. Did you mean Alt & F11, or is that different?

Comment: Sorry! Good spot. I have been working in Access over the last few days, and it's CTRL + G in Access. You are right, ALT + F11 takes you to the VBA Editor. Hopefully, all the other steps I have detailed will make sense and give you the solution. Davy